# Post facebook open graph story action with PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Im trying to post a custom object and action in a user's page. Im obtaining the access token via js api and sending the access token to my server complete the sharing process.

Im wish to post that the user completed a puzzle, therefore defining the object puzzle (with custom puzzle info) and the action completed.

I defined the puzzle object in my server in a sharePuzzlePlayed.php:

```
<html>
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# dooodil: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/dooodil#">
    <meta property="fb:explicitly_shared" content="true" />
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1428286320719613" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Sample Puzzle" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo $image ?>" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo $url ?>" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="puzzle" />
    <title>Dooodil puzzle complete</title>
</head>
</html>
```

and posted using the following code:

```
$message = array(
     'puzzle' => "http://server/information/facebook/sharePuzzlePlayed.php",
      'explicitly_shared' => true
);
try
{
      $postResult = (new FacebookRequest(
          $this->facebookSession, 'POST', '/me/dooodil:completed',$message
      ))->execute()->getGraphObject();

      $graphObjArray = $postResult->asArray();
      ServerLogger::getInstance()->logData("Data from share:".print_r($graphObjArray,true));
 }
 catch(FacebookRequestException $e)
 {
      ServerLogger::getInstance()->logData("Exception occured when posting share data, code: " . $e->getCode());
      ServerLogger::getInstance()->logData("with message: " . $e->getMessage());
 }
```

The whole process works and posts to a given test user i defined in the facebook app. FB responds with an id:

> ---
>
> ENTRY: 11:30:28am
>   -->Data from share:Array ( [id] => 1447883008838539 )

But when I go to the test user profile I cannot see the post!

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Go check the activity log of the user. Not everything posted via API gets shown on timeline.

Comment: Yep, it is shown in activity log! Is there a way to force the post to appear in timeline?

Comment: Since you have `explicitly_shared` already set, there is nothing more you can do AFAIK. (Also that _should_ get it shown on timeline. But maybe it needs to be approved for that first.)

Comment: You need to have explicitly_shared reviewed in order to be displayed on timeline for none developer/admins of your application. This will be done when you submit your open graph action for review (after enabling this).